# How can we capture user events in dom from record.js in Sugar CRM 7.5?

Tags: sugarcrm

How can we capture user events in dom from record.js in Sugar CRM 7.5?

For example: I have a select box in sugar CRM 7.5 record view.
On change of this list i need to hide/show some fields in the interface.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this

- You can make your fields dependent if you only want to show hide the fields [Ref](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Knowledge_Base/02Administration/100Studio_and_Module_Builder/Sugar_Logic/Dependent_Field__Display_Based_on_List_Values/)
- You can register your events in initialize function of record view controller file of your module see the sample code

> this.on('field_name', this.functionName, this);

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, done it through studio using dependent fields

Answer (score 2):

while in record.js you have access to the model object, which is the javascript representation of SugarCRM's Bean object

The SugarCRM model is an extension of a backbone.js model and you can and *should* use [Backbone Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on)

in record.js :

```
initialize : {
     /** initialize code **/
     this.model.on('change:title' , function () {/*...*/})
}
```

However as mentioned beforethere are simpler ways to accomplish this without any javascript or PHP. Please see the studio tool located in the administration panel.